# Training batch_size in tensorflow.keras (version 2.13.0) is not working?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model with Keras. When I'm running `model.fit()`, it seems Keras is trying to copy the whole dataset to my GPU, neglecting the `batch_size` I set in the fit function.
I updated my TensorFlow to 2.13.0 recently, my code worked perfectly with previous versions.

A minimal sample to repeat the problem:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import legacy

def gen_train_data(s):
    X = np.random.random((s, 2000, 50))
    Y = X * 0.5 + 2.0 + np.random.random((s, 2000, 1))
    W = np.ones((s, 2000, 1))
    return X, Y, W

def minimal_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2000, 50))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)
    outputs = x
    min_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    optimizer = legacy.Nadam(learning_rate=0.001, decay=0.977)
    return min_model, optimizer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shape = 100000
    X_train, Y_train, W_train = gen_train_data(shape)
    train_batch_size = 16

    model, optimizer = minimal_model()
    loss = tf.keras.losses.Huber(0.04)

    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, 
        sample_weight_mode="temporal")
    history = model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, 
        batch_size=train_batch_size, epochs=1, shuffle=True, 
        sample_weight=W_train)
```

Error information:

```
2023-08-21 17:11:16.049846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1639] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21173 MB memory: -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090, pci bus id: 0000:b1:00.0, compute capability: 8.9 2023-08-21 17:12:20.632044: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:485] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 37.25GiB (rounded to 40000000000)requested by op _EagerConst
```

where the memory cost is exactly the size of the total dataset. Why `batch_size` is not working?

Comment: You are still loading the full data into memory and the passed batch_size to the fit() will not change that. You should change your logic to use tensor flow datasets or generators, these two traits allow you to load the data efficiently.